# httpwebrequest время ожидания операции истекло

Tags: c++-cli, .net-4.0

Я использую C++ CLI в MVS 2015 Community (.NET 4)

Моя программа работает в потоке. Из потока на форму выводится результат и считываются настройки. Есть статический класс, который работает с httpwebrequest.
А именно (часть класса)

Объявление:

```
ref class http abstract sealed
{
public:
    static String^ httpGet(String^, http_params^);
    static String^ httpPost(String^, String^, http_params^);
};
```

Часть определения

```
String^ http::httpGet(String^ url, http_params ^params)
{
    HttpWebRequest ^HReq = dynamic_cast<HttpWebRequest^>(WebRequest::Create(url));
    HReq->Method = L"GET";
    HReq->ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion::Version11;
    HReq->KeepAlive = false;
    HReq->Referer = params->referer;
    HReq->Timeout = 10000;
    HReq->UserAgent = L"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36";
    HReq->CookieContainer = params->cookie;
    HReq->Accept = L"*/*"; 
    HReq->Headers->Add(L"Accept-Language", L"ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4");
    HReq->Headers->Add(L"Accept-Encoding", L"gzip,deflate,sdch");
    HReq->AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods::GZip;
    HReq->AllowAutoRedirect = params->is_loc;
    if (params->is_loc)
        HReq->MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 10;

    HttpWebResponse ^HRes = dynamic_cast<HttpWebResponse^>(HReq->GetResponse());

    Stream ^res_stream = HRes->GetResponseStream();

    StreamReader ^ StR = gcnew StreamReader(res_stream);
    String ^res = StR->ReadToEnd();
    StR->Close();

    res_stream->Close();

    HRes->Close();

    return res;
}

String^ http::httpPost(String^ url, String^ data, http_params ^params)
{
    HttpWebRequest ^HReq = dynamic_cast<HttpWebRequest^>(WebRequest::Create(url));
    HReq->Method = L"POST";
    HReq->ServicePoint->ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 0;
    HReq->ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion::Version11;
    HReq->ServicePoint->Expect100Continue = false;
    HReq->KeepAlive = false;
    HReq->Referer = params->referer;
    HReq->Timeout = 10000;
    HReq->Accept = L"*/*";
    HReq->Headers->Add(L"Accept-Language",L"ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4");
    HReq->Headers->Add(L"Accept-Encoding", L"gzip,deflate,sdch");
    HReq->AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods::GZip;
    HReq->UserAgent = L"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36";
    HReq->CookieContainer = params->cookie;
    HReq->AllowAutoRedirect = params->is_loc;
    if (params->is_loc)
        HReq->MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 10;
    HReq->ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    array <Byte> ^dd = Encoding::UTF8->GetBytes(data);
    HReq->ContentLength = dd->Length;

    Stream ^srtwr = HReq->GetRequestStream();
    srtwr->Write(dd, 0, dd->Length);
    srtwr->Close();


    String ^res;
    HttpWebResponse ^HRes = dynamic_cast<HttpWebResponse^>(HReq->GetResponse());

    srtwr = HRes->GetResponseStream();

    StreamReader ^StR = gcnew StreamReader(srtwr, Encoding::UTF8);

    res = StR->ReadToEnd();


    StR->Close();

    srtwr->Close();

    HRes->Close();

    return res;
}
```

Проблема в том, что рандомно в

```
Stream ^srtwr = HReq->GetRequestStream();
```

или в

```
srtwr = HRes->GetResponseStream();
```

Не важно, get или post

Вылетает исключение

> Исключение типа "System.Net.WebException" возникло в System.dll, но не
>   было обработано в коде пользователя Дополнительные сведения: Время
>   ожидания операции истекло

Иногда работает нормально, иногда постоянно данное исключение происходит.

Answer (score 2):

Обрабатывать исключение и делать вторую попытку. Сети, они такие, иногда и не работают.

Comment: То есть это единственный выход? Думаю, я просто делаю что-то не так.. Есть ли какие-либо сторонние решения для .NET 4 чтобы отправлять get|post?

Comment: @СтаниславГрот взаимодействие со внешним миром не всегда успешно. В случае ошибки, остается только попытаться еще раз.

Comment: Просто даже в снифферах проблемные запросы не отображаются, как будто они и не отправлялись..